# How to invoke Rhino compiled JavaScript methods (class files) in the Java program?

Tags: java, javascript, compiler-construction, embed, rhino

I compiled following JavaScript file, "test.js", into the "test.class" :

```
var test = (function () {
  var that = {};

  that.addNumbers = function (a, b) {
    return a+b;
  };

  return that;
}());
```

I would like to call the compiled JavaScript function, "test.addNumbers(1,2)", in the simple Java program "run.java" as follows :

```
public class run {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Context cx = Context.enter();

    try {
      Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

      // HOW TO CALL THE METHOD, Test.addNumbers(1,2)?  Please help me!

    } finally {
      Context.exit();
    }
  }
}
```

I tried many ways, but failed.  I read Rhino tutorial and examined many articles and examples, BUT they only show how to call JavaScript methods from the command line or the source file, "test.js".
I need to call the method from the compiled "test.class" file.

Thanks much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), I believe that the JavaScript type `test` does not mean that the resultant Java type is this class. The generated Java type invokes the script code in its constructor; this will not result in exposing `addNumbers` as a Java method.

```
>javap -classpath . test
public class test extends org.mozilla.javascript.NativeFunction implements org.m
ozilla.javascript.Script{
    public test(org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable, org.mozilla.javascript.Contex
t, int);
    public test();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    public final java.lang.Object exec(org.mozilla.javascript.Context, org.mozil
la.javascript.Scriptable);
    public final java.lang.Object call(org.mozilla.javascript.Context, org.mozil
la.javascript.Scriptable, org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable, java.lang.Object[])
;
    public int getLanguageVersion();
    public java.lang.String getFunctionName();
    public int getParamCount();
    public int getParamAndVarCount();
    public java.lang.String getParamOrVarName(int);
    public java.lang.String getEncodedSource();
    public boolean getParamOrVarConst(int);
}
```

Reading between the lines, I'd say you need to map to Java types to do what you want. From the [jsc](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/jsc.html) doc:

> `-implements java-intf-name`
>
> Specifies that a java class
>   implementing the Java interface
>   `java-intf-name` should be generated
>   from the incoming JavaScript source
>   file. Each global function in the
>   source file is made a method of the
>   generated class, implementing any
>   methods in the interface by the same
>   name.

Define this interface:

```
//Adder.java
public interface Adder {
  public int addNumbers(int a, int b);
}
```

Write this implementation:

```
//AdderImpl.js
function addNumbers(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Compile the JavaScript with the arguments `-implements Adder AdderImpl.js`. Invoke the method like so:

```
Adder adder = new AdderImpl();
int n = adder.addNumbers(1, 2);
System.out.println(n);
```

I'd hazard a guess that it was probably necessary to do it this way because of differences in the languages' type systems.

*I used Rhino 1.7R2. For the sake of brevity, I've avoided using packages, etc.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works! I dont need to worry about preparing Context things, instead "new" on the implementation class and just use the interface methods. Fantastic!

Comment: Now, what if you want to add class shutters to the final compiled code.